# how to display a html file stored in s3 in aws in my django template?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to make free learning site . Content of mysite are stored in s3 in html format .How to embed that html code from s3 in to my django app.

Comment: Please show what you tried.. read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

One way you could do this is to load the contents of your s3 html file into an iframe and display it to the user. Assuming you have the contents already parsed from the file you can use.

```
<iframe scrolling="yes" srcdoc="<html>Contents of HTML File here </html>"></iframe>
```

If you want to reference a url, you can wrap it use it this way.

```
<iframe srcdoc="<iframe src='http://aws.amazon.com/path/to/file.html'></iframe>"></iframe>
```